# Does a copied user get the same folder permissions on a share?

Tags: active-directory, network-share, user-management

This should hopefully be an easy question:

Let's say User#1 has explicit Modify permissions to a specific shared folder.

We make a copy of User#1 and call it User#2.

Will User#2 also have explicit permissions on the same share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, permissions are based on the [SID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (unique identifier assigned to every users, groups, etc... )

The newly created user will have a new SID.

You should put your users into groups, and then give permissions on the group instead of users.

Comment: Yep, doing that. We're just trying to identify a situation :) Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: I would only add this, to clarify about what gets copied when you copy a user. If you review your AD Schema there is a part of each attribute that flags it, it is a checkbox. From TechNet:

"You can modify which default attributes are carried over to a newly copied user or specify additional attributes that will be copied to the new user. To do this, open the Active Directory Schema snap-in, view the desired attribute properties, and select (or clear) the Attribute is copied when duplicating user check box. You can modify or add only the attributes that are instances of the user class. "